# Laurent series expansion of sine

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

The problem is : find the expansion of $ \frac {z}{\sin z} $ in the ring $\pi < abs (z) < 2\pi $, if the expansion in $abs (z)<\pi $ is known. How to solve such problems?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576658/proof-that-frac12c-n-d-n-pi-1-if-n-is-odd-for-fz-cscz-and If you understand the answer, it will be easy to modify it to the present situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped.